# Change help text based on select input with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code (the html-attributes are for bootstrap-slider):

```
<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group" id = "time">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="notification_time">How many minutes before an event?</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">  
    <input id="notification_time" name="notification_time" type="text" value="{{current_user.notifications_min}}" data-slider-min="5" data-slider-max="120" data-slider-step="5" data-slider-value="{{current_user.notifications_min}}" data-slider-selection="after">
    </div>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="notifications">E-mail notification</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
      <input name="notifications" id="emailnotification" value="emailnotification" type="checkbox" data-on="success" data-off="danger" data-on-label="Yes" data-off-label="No" {% if current_user.daily_mail %} checked {% endif%}>
    <span class="help-block">You'll get an email **X** minutes before each event</span>  
      </div>
  </div>
```

I want **X** in the above example to automatically change based on the input in `notification_time`. How do I do this?

Comment: Couldn't you just put `{{current_user.notifications_min}}` on the **X** as well?

Comment: No, because that is fed to the form by a database; i.e. that only changes when the page is refreshed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#notification_time').on('change', function () {
    var time = $(this).val();
    $('.help-block').text('You\'ll get an email ' + time + ' minutes before each event');
});
```

**Edit**: note that the `change` event will only fire when you change and leave the focus of the input. Modern browsers support an `input` event or you can try using `keyup` if you wish.

**Edit 2**: after reading the docs on the [slider for bootstrap](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-slider/), try this:

```
$('#notification_time').slider().on('slideStop', function () {
    var time = $('#notification_time').val();
    $('.help-block').text('You\'ll get an email ' + time + ' minutes before each event');
});
```

Comment: This works, but only when I remove the `$('#notification_time').slider()` (http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-slider/). Is there a way to make both your code and the slider work together?

Comment: @Ben so the `#notification_time` input is actually a slider?

Comment: Yes, it is. I just tried your new code; it works like a charm. Thank you!